# how to match string portion with NSArray values in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, nsstring, nsarray

I have following array and search string.

```
NSArray *values =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",@"xyz",@"cba",@"yzx",nil];

NSString *search = @"startcba";
```

I want to search string's end part within an array elements. My expected search result will be @"cba". Please let me know how to find the desire value in array for giving search.

Thanks,

Comment: always the three last characters ? If so, get the substring and send `[myArray indexOfObject:myString]`.

Comment: Sorry, it can be of any length, like :                NSArray *values =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",@"xyz",@"cba",@"yzx",@"Abcd",nil];
 
 NSString *search = @"startabcd";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` to get the elements that satisfy your requirement.

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" %@ ENDSWITH SELF ", search];
NSArray * searchResults = [values filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: You can specify `c` and `d` in the predicate for case and diacritic insensitivity. So, predicate format looks like this `@" %@ ENDSWITH[cd] SELF "`

Comment: Thanks Deepak and EmptyStack for providing easy and exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

The NSPredicates way is great.

Here is an approach with rangeOfString:

```
NSArray *values =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",@"xyz",@"cba",@"yzx",nil];

NSString *search = @"startcba";
NSUInteger searchLength = [search length];
NSString *result = nil;

for (NSString *val in values)
{
    NSUInteger valLength = [val length];
    NSRange expectedRange = NSMakeRange(searchLength - valLength, valLength);
    NSRange rng = [search rangeOfString:val];

    if ( rng.location == expectedRange.location && rng.length == expectedRange.length )
    {
        result = val;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your rangeOfString approach is equally good like deepak's and it can also allow me to find the index of items in the same loop. Sorry, i have to accept deepak's answer as it is exactly what i needed. I appreciate your valuable help.